# Recommended way to create multiple NServiceBus publishers in a single application/process?

Tags: .net, nservicebus

I'm going to have several publishers that are all logical components of a single "application".

Although I try pretty hard to separate concerns (i.e. there are many independent class libraries making up the domain logic), I'd still much rather have just one application to deploy, debug, etc.

All of the examples I've looked at so far seem to rely on putting the publisher information in the app.config, and it looks like I can only declare one publisher that way.

It looks like I might be able to use the `CustomConfigurationSource` method but I feel like I'm missing something far more straightforward and direct.

Is there a simple/recommended way to create multiple publishers (each with a different event type) in a single application, either using the generic host or with self-hosting?

Answer (score 0):

Provided you're following the guidance of each logical publisher publishing different event types where no two logical publishers ever publish the exact same type, you're fine.

Following this enables you to have one or more logical publishers "co-hosted" in a single application process.  The fact that they are talking to the exact same physical database table isn't necessarily a problem because they won't have any overlap with each other and they won't step on each others' toes.

As long as you've done the logical separation in code there isn't any problem with putting them into the same physical process and sharing the same physical resources such as queues and databases.

From there, just fire things up using NServiceBus.Host.exe (for Windows hosting) and you're good to go.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your answer; I am following this guidance (as noted in the question, "each [publisher] with a different event type"), and I'm not worried that it's any kind of problem, I'm just not sure *how to set it up*, since the app.config only allows for one input queue to be configured (which every bus and thus every publisher would be assigned by default - exactly what the guidance says *not* to do). Is there some place where I can specify which queues should be assigned to which publishers?

Comment: If all the Publishers are sharing the same process and subscription storage, I don't see an issue with using the same input queue.  This is just a place for subscription messages to be accepted.  I know you can't configure more that one input queue, and toggling it sounds tough from a maintenance standpoint.

Comment: +1 for Adam's comment.  One thing that I've done is setup a separate publisher "subscription" queue that listens to subscription messages.  It talks to the publisher database and saves subscription requests.  The real publisher code then talks to the same subscription storage.  In this way I don't have to listen on two queues in the same process.